# Blank screenshots on Android tablet

Tags: screenshots, viewsonic-gtablet

I use `ddms` to take screenshots of my phone and it works fine, but when I try to do the same with my tablet I just get a black image. The phone is a Samsung Intercept running Android 2.2; the tablet is a ViewSonic gTablet with Cyanogenmod 7. I found a [forum post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=10971514&postcount=25) that mentions that Tegra devices (like the gTablet) don't use `fb0`, so normal screenshots don't work, but it also claims that screenshots taken through `adb` connections work and they don't for me -- I get the same black image. Is that the reason `ddms` doesn't work on my tablet? Is there a workaround that will let me take screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have one of these device (mine is branded as something else but the US brand is the ViewSonic gTablet). I cannot recall if I have tried to do a screenshot with DDMS or not. I don't know why the forums you read would say adb would work becuase ADB uses the same method as DDMS.

I will try my device when I get home from work today, in the mean time, I have read that these apps should work with the device.

All of these are paid apps, they may have a free/lite version but I dont know if they will work for your issue.
[Screenshot ER](https://market.android.com/details?id=fahrbot.apps.screen.pro1&hl=en) - Requires Root
[Screen Shot It](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.edwardkim.android.screenshotitfull&hl=en) - Requires Root
[No Root Screen Shot It](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.edwardkim.android.screenshotitfullnoroot&hl=en) - NO ROOT REQUIRED (but I am not sure if this works)